# Through an error in Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

I am using below code for iPad. But though an error message in IE 'Object not supported (addEventListener)'

```
function isTextInput(node) {
    return ['INPUT', 'TEXTAREA'].indexOf(node.nodeName) !== -1;
}
document.addEventListener('touchstart', function(e) { 
    if (!isTextInput(e.target) && isTextInput(document.activeElement)) {
    //document.activeElement.blur();
    $('input').blur();
}
}, false);
```

Comment: Hint: __attachEvent__, http://www.javascripter.net/faq/addeventlistenerattachevent.htm

Comment: Thanks Satpal. It's helpfull\

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is because [addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener) is supported only in [IE9+](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener#Browser_compatibility), either you need to use [attachEvent()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/ie/ms536343%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) or since you have jQuery use it

```
$(document).on('touchstart', function (e) {
    if (!isTextInput(e.target) && isTextInput(document.activeElement)) {
        //document.activeElement.blur();
        $('input').blur();
    }
});
```